# How to add a button to the TinyMCE editor in Datalife Engine?

Tags: tinymce, datalife-engine

To add a button in the TinyMCE editor, I have read a lot of things, they were good guides, but none of them specified exactly what files I should add the codes to and to! Please guide me if anyone has information about this. If I want to say exactly what I want, I would say that I want to add a button to the TinyMCE editor toolbar to add the following code to the end of the text:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=
*.pdf
" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" height="500px" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

## Again, I remind you that the codes to be added should be added to which files in Datalife Engine?

As I said, I read a lot of articles about this, but the explanations for putting the codes in the files were insufficient.